# VMWare Workspace ONE SDK for React Native

Tags: react-native

We are developing a mobile application by using React Native for Andriod and iOS, would like to know is there any VMWare Workspace one SDK for React Native?
How the mobile application can access to web services residing behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: Need more information, can you please add more information?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the [vmware-wsone-sdk-reactnative](https://github.com/vmwareairwatchsdk/vmware-wsone-sdk-reactnative)?

I think it's what do you search.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30895271)